# Limit of a function in a weighted Sobolev space

Tags: tag-removed, sobolev-spaces, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

I have a function $f(x)$ in the space $H^{2,-s}(\mathbb{R}^3)$; have this limit sense
$$\lim_{|x-y|\to 0} f(x)$$
? ($y$ is a fixed point)
If i have $f$ in $H^2$ I can say that
$$\lim_{|x-y|\to 0} f(x)=f(y)$$
because $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\subset C(\mathbb{R}^3)$, but in the space $H^{2,-s}$? In general I can say nothing, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure. If you are in $H^{2-s}(\mathbb R^3)$ you can embed in $W^{1,\frac{6}{1+2s}}(\mathbb R^3)$, and from there you can get into $C^{0,\alpha}({\mathbb R}^3)$ by Morrey's inequality, for all $\alpha,s\in (0,1)$ such that $s+\alpha=\frac12$. So, I would say there's plenty of space for you beneath $H^2(\mathbb R^3)$ to still get a continuous function in the end.

Comment: Can you write me your definition of $C^{0,\alpha}$?

Comment: The same used here en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality , from where I've taken the second embedding (I can never remember the embeddings by heart).

Comment: So the limit that I considered in my first answer exists? From your reasoning I deduce that I can find a continuous representative for my function in SH^{2,-s}$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, so I believe.